# SSRS 2008 R2 Querystring parameters Sharepoint Integrated Mode

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I’m trying to run a report via the following url:

```
http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/_vti_bin/ReportServer?http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/reports/Test.rdl
```

However, I get a 401 Unauthorised error.

The reason I am accessing the report this way is so that I can pass some parameters (which I have taken off for now). I want to pass via queyrstring some mdx values which will be used to run the report.

The URL looks like this with the queyrstring parameters.

```
http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/_vti_bin/ReportServer?http://portal/dashboards/hr/reports/reports/Test.rdl&rp:CostCentreCostCentreHierarchy=%5BCost%20Centre%5D.%5BCost%20Centre%20Hierarchy%5D.%26%5B1002%5D&TimeFiscalYearQuarter=%5BTime%5D.%5BFiscal%20Year-Quarter-Month%5D.%5BF%20Quarter%5D.%26%5B20123%5D
```

Basically the parameters are MDX values.

I'm sure this worked for me at one point - but not any more.

I’m hoping it’s a case of missing permissions somewhere?!

Could the issue be related to the _vti_bin folder. I used this as per the article: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx`

Opening the reports via Sharepoint from the respective lists, works fine - the reports run without any errors - its just when I use the _vti_bin url i get this issue. The querystring parameters do not work with the regaular report viewer url which is in the _layouts folder.

If there is a better way to do this then please advise also.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - apparaently each parameter is required to have the rp: prefix.

The only character that needs to be encoded in the mdx value is the ampersand.

Thanks.